# How to update GridView when I update a collection that GridView is binded with?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.5

GridView is binded with some collection. When I delete items from this collection from code-behind, GridView doesn't change its content.

```
private void PriceRange_ValueChanged(object sender, RangeBaseValueChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        SfRangeSlider rangeSlider = sender as SfRangeSlider;
        if (rangeSlider != null)
        {
            double currentMaxValue = Math.Round(rangeSlider.Value);
            if (this.DataContext != null)
            {
                (this.DataContext as SearchViewModel).TicketModels.RemoveAll(x => (GetPriceFromTicket(x.Price) > currentMaxValue));
                var m = (this.DataContext as SearchViewModel).TicketModels.Count;
            }
        }
    }
```

If I trace the m variable I can see that `TicketModels.Count` changes, but I can't see it at UI.
Btw, TicketModels has the `List<>` type, should I change it to `ObservableCollection<>`?

Comment: Have you tried to use `ObservableCollection<>`?

Comment: @Guilherme Oliveira, not yet. ObservableCollection hasn't the RemoveAll method. If I want to use ObservableCollection I will have to change my code in many places. Is it the only way?

Comment: I think so, cause when you use `ObservableCollection<>` it notifies the property change automatically. You could also write an extension method for `RemoveAll`.

Comment: @Guilherme Oliveira, How to write this extention method? It should work with lambda-functions that I use. Sorry, I'm not familiar with C# well.

Comment: Steven already answered your question as you need.

Answer (score 2):

The type of the binding source, i.e. the property declared in the view model that's data bound in the view (`TicketModels` in your example), should be a type that implements `INotifyCollectionChanged`. [`ObservableCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) implements this interface (besides `INotifyPropertyChanged`).

This works because the `Binding` listens to the `INotifyCollectionChanged.CollectionChanged` event, which `ObservableCollection<T>` will raise when elements have been added or removed.

If you need to clear the collection, you can simply use [`ObservableCollection<T>.Clear()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132405%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

I usually make my ObservableCollection's read-only, and then use the following extension method to replace the content when needed.

```
/// <summary>
/// Replaces the content of a collection with the content of another collection.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TSource">The type of elements of <paramref name="source"/>.</typeparam>
/// <param name="source">The target data collection.</param>
/// <param name="sourceCollection">The collection whose elements should be added to the System.Collections.Generic.ICollection&lt;T&gt;.</param>
/// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException"><paramref name="source"/> is <c>null</c>.</exception>
public static void ReplaceContentWith<TSource>(this ICollection<TSource> source, IEnumerable<TSource> sourceCollection)
{
    if (source == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("source");

    source.Clear();
    source.AddRange(sourceCollection);
}
```

Usage:

```
var foo = new ObservableCollection<string>();
var bar = new List<string> { "one", "two", "three" };
foo.ReplaceContentWith(bar);
```

Comment: Can I add INotifyCollectionChanged.CollectionChanged to TicketModels? If it possible, can you give a simple example how to do this?

Comment: Yes, you can modify your `TicketModels` class to implement `INotifyCollectionChanged`.  It's easier to use `ObservableCollection` because it already implements it & it works.  No bugs.

Comment: Like Tony suggested, I would strongly recommend the same. You can implement `INotifyCollectionChanged` on `TicketModels` now, but what if you need another collection class? You won't be able to reuse the code you've written on the `TicketModels` class, unless you implement it in an abstract base class which `TicketModels` then inherits. You're basically re-inventing `ObservableCollection<T>` yourself, then.

Comment: @Steven, I understand, but advisor doesn't allow to change List to ObservableCollection, that's why I need to know how to implement INotifyCollectionChanged.

Comment: splash27, that is going to be very difficult and also unneccesary. I see you have a ViewModel, and you're adapting it's contents from the view. That practice is actually not allowed in the MVVM pattern. You should bind the `Command` property of a button in your view to an `ICommand` implementation of the ViewModel. The `ICommand` then takes care of all the calculations (removing TicketModels if they meet the requirement). You can pass parameters to the `ICommand` by binding a value to the button's `CommandParameter` property (e.g., the rangeslider's value).